# Emacs : Jump to the next line with same indentation

Tags: emacs

Very often, I am stuck searching for the end of loops and methods and classes and end up sifting through all the code which is both time-consuming and frustrating. I would rather skip to go to the next line with same indentation.

Is there any shortcut in emacs to do so?

Comment: See also [Navigate by indentation](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/20900/navigate-by-indentation)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A little improvement on [Stefan's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1025306/318218):

```
(defun jump-to-same-indent (direction)
  (interactive "P")
  (let ((start-indent (current-indentation)))
    (while
      (and (not (bobp))
           (zerop (forward-line (or direction 1)))
           (or (= (current-indentation) 0)
           (> (current-indentation) start-indent)))))
  (back-to-indentation))
```

This function takes a prefix argument (e.g., +1/-1) that designates the number of lines to move over when searching for a line with the same indentation. It also skips empty lines. Finally one can bind both forward and backward searches using keybindings similar to `M-{` and `M-}` for paragraphs:

```
(global-set-key [?\C-{] #'(lambda () (interactive) (jump-to-same-indent -1)))
(global-set-key [?\C-}] 'jump-to-same-indent)
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any, but something like

```
(defun jump-to-next-same-indent ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((start-indent (current-indentation)))
    (while
      (and (not (bobp))
           (zerop (forward-line 1))
           (> (current-indentation) start-indent))))
  (back-to-indentation))
```

should work, which you could bind for example to <kbd>M-p</kbd> with

```
(global-set-key [?\M-p] #'jump-to-next-same-indent)
```

Answer (score 0):

A little improvement on [P.B.'s](https://superuser.com/a/1048475/85937) answer ;)

```
(defun jump-to-same-indent (direction)
  (interactive "P")
  (let ((start-indent (current-indentation)))
    (while
        (and (not (bobp))
             (zerop (forward-line (or direction 1)))
             (or (= (current-indentation)
                    (- (line-end-position) (line-beginning-position)))
                 (> (current-indentation) start-indent)))))
  (back-to-indentation))
```

This will also jump to the next line with no indentation, previously it would jump to the bottom of the file if current line was not indented.

Comment: Ok, but it doesn't respect behavior "jump to same as CURSOR indentation" (for example if I put the cursor on "(while" in your code then move 3 lines down and want quickly return back

Answer (score 0):

You can also use regexp search for that. For instance I had to navigate through all lines at the same level of indentation in a Yaml file - those lines were indented at to spaces in my case. I used:
M-C-s ^  \w
Then keep pressing C-s to navigate to the next line or C-r to navigate to the previous line.